# Alamofire: Issue sending array in parameter

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, alamofire

I'm trying to send an array in a POST request parameter in the following format:

```
{  "ratings": [{
   "safety_rating_id": 105,
   "schedule_job_id": 18,
   "score": 9,
   "submission_id": 27
}, 
{
   "safety_rating_id": 105,
   "schedule_job_id": 18,
   "score": 9,
   "submission_id": 27
}]
}
```

I have tried to wrapping my array but I was thrown this error:

> Contextual type 'Array' (aka 'Array>') cannot be used with dictionary literal

**POST request code:**

```
 let comments: Array<[String:AnyObject]> = [
        "ratings" : [
                [
                    "safety_rating_id" : 106,
                    "schedule_job_id" : 18,
                    "score" : 10,
                    "submission_id" : 27
                ],
                [
                    "safety_rating_id" : 105,
                    "schedule_job_id" : 18,
                    "score" : 9,
                    "submission_id" : 27
                ]
            ]
    ]
Alamofire.request(.POST, endPoint, headers: Auth_header, parameters: comments)
        .validate()
        .responseData {
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            print(json)
            onCompletion()
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            onError?(error)
        }

    }
```

[image: array in parameter error]

Answer (score 0):

You write

```
let comments: Array<[String:AnyObject]>
```

but the content you put in there is a Dictionary, not an array.

Change `comments`'s signature to a simple dictionary:

```
let comments: [String:AnyObject] = [
    "ratings" : [
        [
            "safety_rating_id" : 106,
            "schedule_job_id" : 18,
            "score" : 10,
            "submission_id" : 27
        ],
        [
            "safety_rating_id" : 105,
            "schedule_job_id" : 18,
            "score" : 9,
            "submission_id" : 27
        ]
    ]
]
```

Or, if you need the full type:

```
let comments: [String:[[String:Int]]] = [
    "ratings" : [
        [
            "safety_rating_id" : 106,
            "schedule_job_id" : 18,
            "score" : 10,
            "submission_id" : 27
        ],
        [
            "safety_rating_id" : 105,
            "schedule_job_id" : 18,
            "score" : 9,
            "submission_id" : 27
        ]
    ]
]
```